# How to create Vertical Progress Bar - IOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I am trying to create a vertical progress bar. But the problem is my code is working on **IOS11 or Above** but on **IOS9** it's not working.

On **IOS11 Or Above** it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Gwg.png)

But on **IOS9** it looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwfr4.png)

My Code:

```
let progressBar: UIProgressView = {
    let prgressView = UIProgressView()
    prgressView.progress = 0.7
    prgressView.progressTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.21, blue: 0.33, alpha: 1)
    prgressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.blue
    prgressView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.5
    prgressView.clipsToBounds = true
    prgressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / -2)
    prgressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return prgressView
}()
```

layoutSubview()

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let width = progressBar.bounds.width
    let height = progressBar.bounds.height

    progressBar.bounds.size.width = height
    progressBar.bounds.size.height = width
}
```

viewDidLoad()

```
    self.addSubview(progressBar)
    progressBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    progressBar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    progressBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.5).isActive = true
    progressBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
```

I am following this tutorial to create vertical progressView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifekgTtb0rQ&t=1070s

Comment: As of September 3, 2018, [95% of devices are iOS10 or higher](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) so.. why sweat it? Just set your minimum iOS version and be done with it. This isn't like Android where people can choose an OS willy-nilly. Once people get the notification that there's a new version, they typically install it. And there's no going back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make your code work just fine under iOS 9 and iOS 12 by making two changes to the code you posted:

1. Remove `layoutSubviews`. You have set constraints. Do not also attempt to modify the view's frame directly.
2. Swap the width and height constraints. Think about the size of the progress bar if you didn't apply the transform. You want the width to be 250 and the height to be 22.5. The transform doesn't change this. The transform only makes it look like it's 250 tall but it is still 250 wide.

In short, remove `layoutSubviews` and fix your constraints to:

```
progressBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
progressBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.5).isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes I already tried this but the problem comes when i try to apply some topAnchor or bottomAnchor the anchors point starts according to its height which is 22.5

Comment: That's expected. Again, the constraints apply to the view without the transform. So if you want the "top" of the vertical progress bar to be 40 points from the top, you really need to set the constraint to `(width - height) / 2 + offset` or `(250 - 22.5) / 2 + 40`.

Comment: And at this point you are beyond your original question since this is not specific to any iOS version.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: You can also `override var intrinsicContentSize` to return a CGSize with the height and width swapped. For example, `CGSize(width: rotatedView.intrinsicContentSize.height, heigh: rotatedView.intrinsicContentSize.width)`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not so difficult just rotate the progressbar with angle property of UIView named as transform

```
progressBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
```

Comment: progressBar* rather than progress

Comment: You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69219215/edit) button to modify your answer, instead of posting a comment. :)

Comment: oh thank you i was busy in coding so i couldnt see that buttons xD